# Videojs in Chrome on Android doesn't show poster

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, video.js

I have a video on this page:
https://job.id/2044/telemarketing-executive-kota-bekasi

On all devices & browsers it works fine except Google Chrome on Android. The poster image does not show. Any suggestion how to get poster image to show?

Videojs viewed using Chrome on Android

[image: Videojs viewed using Chrome on Android]

Videojs viewed using other browser on Android

[image]

The video emdedded as:

```
<video id="video-1" 
       class="vjs-tech" 
       preload="auto" 
       data-setup="{fluid: true}" 
       poster="https://d1gajg4ezrqrup.cloudfront.net/live/video/advertiser/1/6/thumbs-cce3c4bb-9b00-4af9-8cb0-07b07201886c-00001.png">
       <source src="https://d1gajg4ezrqrup.cloudfront.net/live/video/advertiser/1/6/mp4-cce3c4bb-9b00-4af9-8cb0-07b07201886c.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="https://d1gajg4ezrqrup.cloudfront.net/live/video/advertiser/1/6/hls-cce3c4bb-9b00-4af9-8cb0-07b07201886c.ts" type="video/hls">
       <source src="https://d1gajg4ezrqrup.cloudfront.net/live/video/advertiser/1/6/webm-cce3c4bb-9b00-4af9-8cb0-07b07201886c.webm" type="video/webm">
       <p class="vjs-no-js">
         blah..
       </p>
</video>
```

Comment: Don't see a video in that page on any browser, and your screenshots are of iOS, not Android.

Comment: Hello Misterben, thanks for your reply. The screenshots were taken on Android and then forwarded to IPhone. I have updated. The video is on the page too now. Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `data-setup='{"fluid": true, "aspectRatio": "16:9"}'`. It's fixed in video.js 5.13 (pre-release), but here fluid mode is collapsing the player on Android on cellular networks because Chrome overrides `preload` to `node`, and there's no other sizing information.

Comment: Hello Misterben, thank you very much. This indeed fixed the issue. Unfortunately stackoverflow won't allow me to accept your comment as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.
    data-setup='{"fluid": true, "aspectRatio": "16:9"}'.

It's fixed in video.js 5.13 (per-release), but here fluid mode is collapsing the player on Android on cellular networks because Chrome overrides preload to node.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. In Chrome the poster would flash for a split second and then disappear. Fixed it by setting preload to false: `preload="false"`